# Beginner Project - Pong - "Ball Script" is kinda buggy :(

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started programming my first computer game today and therefore I picked an easy one: Pong.

The core game is already working but I'm currently trying to add some features like a velocity increase, every time **player1** scores. (**enemy** is currently also a controllable character put I'm planing to create a simple KI for that). It works out well in the beginning but at some point during the game, the **ball** starts bugging, means: the **ball** isn't bouncing away from the **players1**'s character box anymore and is trying to keep going in the direction it bounced to after colliding with the **enemy**. Is the speed too high? Do I have to change something about the **players1**'s box?

Video how it looks like: https://youtu.be/qzHGoQtRmEM

The script is currently looking like that:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics.Tracing;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    //variables
    public float speed;
    public float restartspeed;
    int scorePlayer1;
    int scoreEnemy;
    public Text txtPlayer1;
    public Text txtEnemy;
    public float pausetime;
    bool quit = false;

    
    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(1, 0) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        
    }
   //Collision Physics
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        //print(col.gameObject.name);

        if (col.gameObject.name == "Player1")
        {
            //Collision Player1
            float y = hitObject(transform.position, col.transform.position, col.collider.bounds.size.y);
            //Calculate Direction
            Vector2 dir = new Vector2(1, y);
            //Directionvector Physics
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = dir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Enemy")
        {
            //collision Enemy
            float y = hitObject(transform.position, col.transform.position, col.collider.bounds.size.y);
            //Calculate Direction
            Vector2 dir = new Vector2(-1, y);
            //Directionvector Physics
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = dir * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (col.gameObject.name == "WallLeft")
        {
            scorePlayer1 = scorePlayer1 + 1;
            txtPlayer1.text = scorePlayer1.ToString();
            //Restart with a pause x sec
            StartCoroutine(waiter());
        }
        if (col.gameObject.name == "WallRight")
        {
            scoreEnemy = scoreEnemy + 1;
            txtEnemy.text = scoreEnemy.ToString();
            //Restart with a pause of x sec
            StartCoroutine(waiter());
        }
    }

    float hitObject(Vector2 ballPos, Vector2 playerPos, float playerhight)
    {
        return (ballPos.y - playerPos.y) / playerhight;
    }

    //pausefunction + reset to origin
    IEnumerator waiter()
    {
        float counter = 0;
        Vector2 temp = new Vector2(0, 0);
        gameObject.transform.position = temp;
        Vector2 freeze = new Vector2(0, 0);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = freeze;

        float waitTime = pausetime;

        while (counter < waitTime)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            Debug.Log("Waited for: " + counter + "seconds");
            if (quit)
            {
                yield break;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
        //push ball again to players direction with higher velocity
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(1, 0) * (restartspeed + scorePlayer1);
        
    }

}
```

Lots of love to everyone ^^ (Sorry if the Script is too long but i dont know which lines are relevant for the problem)

Comment: Try setting Rigidbody2D.collisionDetectionMode to CollisionDetectionMode2D.Continuous

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I already did that :(

Comment: I used a different approach in the past and it worked quite well. I simply kept the ball velocity constant (velocity = velocity.normalized * speed) and let Unity handle collisions for me, except for screen borders. Perhaps you could try that, if nothing else works out.

Comment: video link is down

Comment: Yea it also worked for me until i tried to increase the velocity, but i was kinda trying to add that as a feature to increase the difficulty over time. But thanks for the help <3

Comment: @Lotan ah sorry, had it on private instead of not listed

Comment: this won't fix the bug, is another way to implement it: what about add bounceable materials to your players/ball?

Comment: Another problem could be that you're not controlling if the coroutine has ended before calling it again, try to check that

Comment: @Lotan I already added a Physics Material 2D with 0 Friction and 1 Bounciness but it somehow doesn't change much :/ and the coroutine always ends before calling it again, that's because the ball is frozen until it has ended and it can only be activated again when the ball touches the wall. But I noticed that the bug only happens to the Player but not to the enemy character. Thanks a lot for your time btw!

Comment: @Lotan it kinda has to do something with the speed and the transform, i managed that it wasn't perfect but at least the strong bug wasn't showing up again. I thought it works now and then adjusted the position of the players. After that the bug showed up even stronger than before.

Comment: Is this component the only thing that deals with the ball? There could be something else, external, messing with the velocity.

Comment: @Nikaas The velocity is only influenced by the variables of the ball and (probably) by the 2D material on the Ball (Bounciness 1). I noticed now that depending on where the player is positioned the max. of velocity is changing. f. e before changing the position of my player it was a max of 8 now its only 6.5 before the bug starts happening

Comment: Alright I managed to get rid of that bug. Keeping the velocity during the round seems to be the only option to prevent this from happening. The velocity now increases after the round has ended. Not 1:1 the thing I wanted but close enough. Thank you guys all for your help!